# Fuse camel use bindingStyle=SimpleConsumer rsserver options and body response is empty

Tags: json, apache-camel, jbossfuse

I need receiver in message response json the new  header field.After the send the new header and body to rest soapUI or client . For Manage response header and body i have modify my route whit the options bindingStyle = SimpleConsumer but now in the soapUI see only header but the body is empty . First this operation ( bindingStyle = Default ) i saw the body response but do not I saw the header .

(I'm using camel 2.12)
Who can help me ?

```
<route id="mainid">
        <from uri="cxfrs:bean:rsServer?resourceClasses=xxxx&amp;bindingStyle=SimpleConsumer"/>
        <doTry>
            <routingSlip uriDelimiter=",">
                <simple>direct:${header.operationName}</simple>
            </routingSlip>
            <doCatch>
                .....
            </doCatch>
        </doTry>
    </route>
    ...
    <route id="routeid">
        <from uri="direct:postmethod" />
        <removeHeaders pattern="Camel*" />
        <to uri="jetty:{{baseUrl}}{{uri}}" />
    </route>
    ...
```

Comment: Please show your code and you get compared to what you actually want so it is easier to help you.